# How to protect sensitive data on a SPA using JWT tokens

Tags: javascript, api, single-page-application, jwt

I'm thinking about making an app with javascript and make it a SPA.

Using JWT tokens to authenticate the users and set the user roles on the app, what is the best way to protect sensitive content?

Using html templates for logged pages is bad? Should i return always the sensitive content from the api?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything dynamic should be passed through your web service. If you won't use anything improperly (like using SQL drivers without injection prevention) there won't be anything unsafe (for at least first stage).

Also, to prevent MiM attacks, you should use SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt your JWT. Such encryption is defined in the [RFC7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516).

Depending on the programming language used on server side and client side (JS) , you may find libraries that support the JWE.

At [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), you will find a list of those libraries.